Common Ground Between Arduino and ESP32 - Can I Re-use the ESP32 GND Pin for a Potential Divider
I am trying to connect an ESP32 to an Arduino Mega via Serial Communication using the UART 2 ports on both microcontroller boards.
There needs to be a common ground between the ESP32 and Arduino. Hence I have connected the ESP32 GND and Arduino GND pins to the negative power rail of a breadboard.
The Arduino Rx2 has been directly connected to the ESP32 Tx2
I need to use a potential divider to convert the Arduino Tx HIGH output from 5V to 3.3V for the ESP32 Rx2.
Main Question: Can I connect the same ESP32 GND pin (used in the GND to GND connection) to Resistor 2 in the potential divider. In other words, is the dark blue wire that connects the 20K resistor to the GND power rail of the breadboard correct. Will current from the 20K resistor flow to the Arduino, ESP32 or both.
See the Circuit below

Also, according to this other question in the URL below, the answer provided by Madivad says that

if you are using the same power source, then they probably have a common ground.

In my circuit, The Arduino and ESP32 both share the same 9V power supply. So does this mean I don't even need to connect the GND of my Arduino and the GND of my ESP32 to the negative power rail on the breadboard..
Wired serial connection between two Arduinos - do they need a common Ground (GND)?

What software did you use to make this drawing?

This: https://www.cirkitstudio.com/

What you have done is great!
Yes, technically you have already grounded both together with the black wire on your diagram, but you need to run the blue wire to one of the two to create the voltage divider. Connecting the breadboard ground to both devices in this case is a good thing.
Note: There are cases where you want to keep the grounds separate, and cases where you need to tie the grounds together separately. In your case it isn't necessary to do it either way.
If you need to level shift multiple signals, you can purchase a chip that has multiple lines and better efficiency than a voltage divider.

Ok, thanks the answer. Why is it that Connecting the breadboard ground to both devices in this case is a good thing. Will current from the potential divider flow to the GND of the Arduino and GND of the ESP32?

You're just lowering the impedance of the ground path which can make your voltage divider more accurate, and your signal a little cleaner.
